# Upgrade items on shop menu

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, inventory

I made a game and I made a Magnet upgrade and I have 8 game objects to set active 1 by 1 every time when I upgrade the magnet and I have (int upgrade = 0;).

But when I upgrade these game objects it's set active, but if I quit the game and start again all these game objects are FALSE.

How can I make e.g if I upgrade to (int upgrade = 6) and to make my game objects active only from element 0 to element 6. I do upgradeMagnet(); to void Update but its make active only 1 game object depends from (int upgrade) if (int upgrade) is 5 and only game object element 5 is active.

[image: screenshot]

```
    public GameObject[] upgranded;
    public int upgrade = 0;

    public void upgrandeMagnetButton()
    {
        upgrade += 1;
        upgradeMagnet();
    }


        void upgradeMagnet()
    {
        if (upgranded[upgrade])
        {
            upgranded[upgrade].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should store your upgrade value in player preference and read from that.

Comment: i made that but its show only one game object e.g. if upgrade value is 5 and its show game object element 5.

Comment: I don't see it in your snippet. In the Start function simply set a for loop to activate all items.

Answer (score 1):

simply activate them in your start.

```
void Start(){

   upgrade = load from player prefs here
   int count = upgrade+1;
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      upgranded[i].SetActive(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: I wrote this before but didn`t work give me a NullReference error.

Comment: You need to spend a bit more time learning basic C# and basic syntax. Your first element in your array is empty.

Comment: Thanks now work all fine but last game object it`s stay always false after load playerprefs.

Comment: E.g. if i upgrade value 4 after reload the game and go to upgrade it`s shows 3 value game object and 4 it`s doesn`t show.

Comment: `int count = upgrade+1` and use count in the for loop instead of upgrade. Check the edit. Or you can simply use = instead of <